# Server 2008 DNS/Hostname Lookups Giving Out Wrong NIC

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008

So I have a Server 2008 machine which also acts as a PDC, and provides DNS to all other machines.  Now, the server has 2 NICs, one on a 172.16.0.0/24 LAN, and one on a 192.168.47.0/24 LAN.  Every other machine on the network has one NIC, and belongs to one network or the other.

DHCP is working fine, but hostname/DNS lookups using the server name of the PDC sometimes resolves to the wrong NIC.

Now, DNS does have hostname entries for the pdc for both addresses, but I can’t have a computer not on that network getting a resolved address it can’t reach.

Ex: Computer pdc1 has addresses 192.168.47.1 and 172.16.0.1.  Client client1 has a NIC physically on the 192.168.47 network.  For that reason, DHCP works fine, it gets an address.  However, when it looks up the address for pdc1, it gets 172.16.0.1, which isnt reachable and causes lots of problems.

My question is, what is the standard way to prevent this situation? I know I’m not the only one with a PDC on separate NICs, where the client computers need to look up the server name and get the address on the network it’s actually on.

I know a cheap solution is to add the correct address to each clients host file, but this is a workaround since the relationship is now managed on each client pc and not the domain controller.

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: `My question is, what is the standard way to prevent this situation?` - Connect the server only to one of the networks and use routing to facilitate communication with the other network.

Comment: FYI there is no such thing as a PDC anymore. Now they are FSMO Role Masters.

Comment: @joeqwerty Or connect the server to both networks and configure routing properly.

Comment: @kasperd what do you mean by configure the routing? Packets are already implicitly routed through the correct nic on the server to make it to the client machine.  It's not like I'm losing traffic, I'm just resolving the wrong lookup name for a particular client PC.  How would the configuration of the routing table help hostname lookup?

Comment: @joeqwerty that really isn't an option, and even if it were, having multiple servers just so each can only be connected to one LAN doesn't really seem like the right solution.

Comment: @user5870571 I'll try to remember the correct terminology but it seems like everyone understood what I meant...

Comment: Well... you wouldn't have multiple servers. You would have one server... connected to one network... then you'd have a router to route traffic between the networks... which is a widely implemented scenario for companies that keep their servers on a separate network from their end user machines.

Comment: @prelic With properly configured routing every host on either network can send packets to any of the addresses and your routers know how to get the packets there.

Comment: @kasperd packets are already going to the right place.  Even if a client got an incorrect domain controller address and I set up routing to get it to the domain controller, the name is used for more than communication, so I really need DNS to resolve the DCs hostname to the correct address, and by correct, I mean the one that is on the same LAN as the client.  Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Additionally, dual-homing or multi-homing a Domain Controller has been discouraged by Microsoft since Windows 2000.

Comment: @joeqwerty this is a relatively small network (10 client machines plus a bunch of single board computers on the other network), so I'd rather keep extra routing equipment out of the loop if I can make it work on the server.  Using priority/address guessing instead of round robin for DNS is probably the most straight forward way to do what I want, as long as it works as advertised.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @joeqwerty fair point, but setting up secondary domain controllers or any other servers just for name resolution is way overkill for my small network.  I'd rather skip AD and use the stupid hosts file rather than up the complexity to include multiple domain controllers just so I can have two exclusive LANs.  Maybe I have misunderstood your comment, though.

Comment: Understood. I'm not trying to be a downer, I'm just pointing out that your configuration is discouraged by Microsoft, is discouraged by system administrators, and will present challenges... such as the one you're currently experiencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Microsoft DNS server use round robin when serving DNS queries. It means it returns one or another address in circural fashion. 
In your case, you should reconfigure it to use network prioritization, according to this document:

[DNS subnet priorities](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961422.aspx)

Comment: I thought dns priorities would just prefer one over any other, but it seems like it prioritizes based on similarity to the originating requesting computers IP address.  Is that right? That might be just what I need.

Comment: Yes, similarity is taken into account, on ip or mask level

Comment: That seems like exactly what I need, thanks.  Marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the standard way to prevent this situation?

Do not use multihome, use routing to ... route between Networks.

Comment: I don't think this about routing.  If I only have one computer, and it has 2 LANs, and it's a DNS server, all I want is to know is which ip is chosen if I say "ping computername".  Turns out it isn't some round robin thing, it has to do with network binding order.  I don't think routing comes into play here.  I'm not positive of that, but intuitively it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the order in which an IP is chosen during DNS host name lookup is based on the network adapter binding order.  This seems to solve the issue.

Comment: AKA "routing" ...